# How to convert dataframe according to time and corresponding content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Dataframe like this

|  | user_id | day | w | w_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | user01 | 2021-08-01 | [887, 665, 793, 800,... | 162.14, 0.0, 182.84, 229.67..... |
| 1 | user01 | 2021-08-02 | [796, 981, 445, 575,... | 33.33, 315.87, 182.84, 201.39... |

Each field of 'w' and 'w_4' has 1440 pieces of data, and I want to transform to one per minute and corresponding to each data in the w and w_4 columns:

|  | user_id | day | w | w_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | user01 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 887 | 162.14 |
| 1 | user01 | 2021-08-01 00:01:00 | 665 | 0.0 |
| 2 | user01 | 2021-08-01 00:02:00 | 793 | 182.84 |
| 3 | user01 | 2021-08-01 00:03:00 | 800 | 229.67 |
| ... | ...... | ................... | ... | ..... |
| 1440 | user01 | 2021-08-02 00:00:00 | 796 | 33.33 |
| 1441 | user01 | 2021-08-02 00:01:00 | 981 | 315.87 |
| 1442 | user01 | 2021-08-02 00:01:00 | 445 | 182.84 |
| ... | ...... | ................... | ... | ..... |

I have try  `reshape('1Min')` but it can't change to what I want.
Is this the correct solution? Or is there another solution?

Comment: can you provide code of example?

Answer (score 1):

**This solution assumes that the length of the 'w' and 'w_4' lists is the same for each row.**

you can use pandas to do that.
Assuming that "df" is your dataframe, you can define a function that expands rows:

```
def expand_rows(df):
    new_rows = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        day = datetime.strptime(row['day'], '%Y-%m-%d')
        for i in range(len(row['w'])):
            new_row = row.copy()
            new_row['day'] = day + timedelta(minutes=i)
            new_row['w'] = row['w'][i]
            new_row['w_4'] = row['w_4'][i]
            new_rows.append(new_row)
    return pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

expanded_df = expand_rows(df)
```

Results:

```
 user_id                 day    w     w_4
0  user01 2021-08-01 00:00:00  887  162.14
1  user01 2021-08-01 00:01:00  665    0.00
2  user01 2021-08-01 00:02:00  793  182.84
3  user01 2021-08-01 00:03:00  800  229.67
4  user01 2021-08-02 00:00:00  796   33.33
5  user01 2021-08-02 00:01:00  981  315.87
6  user01 2021-08-02 00:02:00  445  182.84
7  user01 2021-08-02 00:03:00  575  201.39
```

Answer (score 1):

hard to know your exact example. so need your code of example

i guess and make similar example:

```
data = [['user01', '2021-08-01', [887, 665, 793, 800], '162.14, 0.0, 182.84, 229.67'], 
        ['user01', '2021-08-02',    [796, 981, 445, 575], '33.33, 315.87, 182.84, 201.39']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['user_id', 'day', 'w', 'w_4'])
```

`df`

```
    user_id day         w                       w_4
0   user01  2021-08-01  [887, 665, 793, 800]    162.14, 0.0, 182.84, 229.67
1   user01  2021-08-02  [796, 981, 445, 575]    33.33, 315.87, 182.84, 201.39
```

`w` columns is list and `w_4` columns is strings

**Code**

To make a complete minimal and reproducible example, I'll make the period 6h since it's 8 data.

```
(df
 .assign(w_4= df['w_4'].str.split(','))
 .explode(['w', 'w_4'])
 .assign(day=pd.date_range('2021-08-01', periods=8, freq='6h')))
```

`output`

```
    user_id day                 w   w_4
0   user01  2021-08-01 00:00:00 887 162.14
0   user01  2021-08-01 06:00:00 665 0.0
0   user01  2021-08-01 12:00:00 793 182.84
0   user01  2021-08-01 18:00:00 800 229.67
1   user01  2021-08-02 00:00:00 796 33.33
1   user01  2021-08-02 06:00:00 981 315.87
1   user01  2021-08-02 12:00:00 445 182.84
1   user01  2021-08-02 18:00:00 575 201.39
```

you can change `periods` and `freq` in `date_range` func for your 2880 datas per 1min

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 3 steps:

- Create column with list of time offsets
- explode list columns
- construct datetime from date and time offsets

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.width = 0


# original table
minutes_in_day = 1440
table = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user_id": ["user01", "user01"],
        "day": ["2021-08-01", "2021-08-02"],
        "w": [np.random.randint(0, 1000, minutes_in_day), np.random.randn(minutes_in_day)],
        "w_4": [np.random.randint(0, 1000, minutes_in_day), np.random.randn(minutes_in_day)],
    },
)
table = table.astype({"day": "datetime64[ns]"})
print(table)

# create column with time-of-the-day offsets
table["offset_from_day_start"] = [
    pd.timedelta_range(start="0 days", end="1 day", freq="1min", closed="left").tolist()
] * len(table)
print(table)

# explode (for multi-column explode pandas version 1.3 or newer is required)
exploded = table.explode(column=["w", "w_4", "offset_from_day_start"], ignore_index=True)

# construct datetime from date and time offsets
exploded['day'] = exploded['day'] + exploded['offset_from_day_start']
exploded = exploded.loc[:, ["user_id", "day", "w", "w_4"]]
print(exploded)
```

Output:

```
  user_id        day                                                  w                                                w_4
0  user01 2021-08-01  [896, 522, 204, 950, 476, 667, 769, 475, 253, ...  [745, 604, 81, 539, 471, 934, 851, 629, 724, 3...
1  user01 2021-08-02  [0.8412346473685158, 0.794899605201405, 1.2225...  [1.9387241208534098, -1.7432370088087925, -1.6...
```

```
  user_id        day                                                  w                                                w_4                              offset_from_day_start
0  user01 2021-08-01  [896, 522, 204, 950, 476, 667, 769, 475, 253, ...  [745, 604, 81, 539, 471, 934, 851, 629, 724, 3...  [0 days 00:00:00, 0 days 00:01:00, 0 days 00:0...
1  user01 2021-08-02  [0.8412346473685158, 0.794899605201405, 1.2225...  [1.9387241208534098, -1.7432370088087925, -1.6...  [0 days 00:00:00, 0 days 00:01:00, 0 days 00:0...
```

```
     user_id                 day         w       w_4
0     user01 2021-08-01 00:00:00       896       745
1     user01 2021-08-01 00:01:00       522       604
2     user01 2021-08-01 00:02:00       204        81
3     user01 2021-08-01 00:03:00       950       539
4     user01 2021-08-01 00:04:00       476       471
...      ...                 ...       ...       ...
2875  user01 2021-08-02 23:55:00 -1.081775  0.280977
2876  user01 2021-08-02 23:56:00 -0.550186 -0.385036
2877  user01 2021-08-02 23:57:00  0.164408 -0.031307
2878  user01 2021-08-02 23:58:00  1.234133 -1.146288
2879  user01 2021-08-02 23:59:00  0.888352  0.963938

[2880 rows x 4 columns]
```